# AxDSOFramer exception in the Open method

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, excel-interop, dsoframer

I'm newbie in the use of `AxDSOFramer` . I have this simple code

```
 Try
   strAnnexeFile = "C:\test\Annexe.xlsx"
   AxFramerControl2.Open(strAnnexeFile, False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
 Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
                AxFramerControl2.Close()
 End Try
```

but I got this exception :

> *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010001): L’appel a été rejeté par l’appelé.    at DSOFramer._FramerControl.Open(Object
>   Document, Object ReadOnly, Object ProgId, Object WebUsername, Object
>   WebPassword)    at AxDSOFramer.AxFramerControl.Open(Object document,
>   Object readOnly, Object progId, Object webUsername, Object
>   webPassword)    at
>   projet1.UserControls.Commun.AnnexeLibre..ctor(String strAnnexeName) in
>   C:\projet1\UserControls\Commun\AnnexeLibre.vb:line 44*

I'd like to know :

1. Why this happens?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this, but its working fine on my system. I have downloaded the framer control from http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Developer-Support-Office-Framer-Control-Sample-KB-311765/3000-2206_4-10732960.html and tested on fx 4.5

Comment: Just to clarify have you ms-office installed in these system?

Comment: @akfkmupiwu Office 2013

Comment: I have tried with multiple scenarios like making file/folder readonly, removing the file from location, wrong file name passing and even renaming the Excel exe itself, but not able to reproduce. Its giving proper exception messages, but not this error.

Comment: What .Net framework version  you used? the mine is 4.0

Comment: DsoFramer was discontinued just before Office 2010 shipped.  Already very troublesome with Office 2007, it doesn't work anymore for later versions.  OLE is dead and buried and won't come back.  Instead of embedding an Office program, they now only support embedding you.  Write an add-in.